Place caption next to subfigure and don't advance the figure counter
Based on the comments on this question, I am trying to put a caption next to a subfigure below another subfigure. This is the code I currently have:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:top}%
        \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}%
    \end{subfigure}\\%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}%
        \vspace{0pt}%
        \caption{This will be the caption\label{fig:full}}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \vspace{0pt}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}%
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:bottom}%
        \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}%
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\noindent \ref{fig:top} \\ \ref{fig:bottom} \\ \ref{fig:full}

\end{document}

The refs at the bottom print:

1a 
2a 
1

Clearly, the second one should be "1b" instead. I think placing the caption already resets the subfig counter and advances the figure counter. Then, when the second subfigure is placed, it starts at "2a". How can I fix this?

Simplest quick and dirty solution: Box the second subfigure before you use the \caption and then use that box:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:top}%
        \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}%
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \sbox0{\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}%
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:bottom}%
        \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}%
    \end{subfigure}}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}%
        \vspace{0pt}%
        \caption{This will be the caption\label{fig:full}}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill\usebox0
\end{figure}

\noindent \ref{fig:top} \\ \ref{fig:bottom} \\ \ref{fig:full}
\end{document}



Thanks, this works for this example. For my actual document, I have the issue that the caption minipage hangs below the entire figure now.

Ah, my subfigure was not t-aligned. That fixed it.
